# Explain the positive values of a term in an inequality

Tags: inequality

I'm solving this inequality:

$$x^4+5x^2 \geq 36$$

I have advanced to this point:

$$ x^4+5x^2-36\geq 0$$

I established that $$ u= x^2$$

Therefore $$ x^4+5x^2-36=(u-4)(u+9)$$
$$ (u-4)= (x+2)(x-2)$$
$$ (u+9)= (x^2+9)$$
$$(x+2)(x-2)(x^2+9)\geq 0$$
$$ x\leq -2 \ x\geq 2$$
As you can see I have already solved the inequality, but I need to explain why all the values of $(x^2+9)$ are positive without using square root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

$$x^2 \ge 0,$$

we have

$$x^2+9 \ge 9 >0$$

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality $$(x+2)(x-2)(x+9)\geq 0$$ Should have been $$(x+2)(x-2)(x^2+9)\geq 0$$

You can ignore $$(x^2+9)$$ because $$(x^2+9)\ge 9 >0$$it is always positive.

Solving $$(x+2)(x-2)\geq 0$$ is a piece of cake and I let you enjoy it.